# Root device changes from /dev/sda to /dev/sdf (Debian)

Tags: boot, grub, udev, usb-drive

I just replaced the PSU of my aging PC because it was unstable. After re-assembling my PC it failed to boot with "gave up waiting for root". I was thrown into a shell and I could see that all my harddisks had been named `/dev/sdf` or later and the respective partitions were all there, of course with equally unusual device names.

**Root is now /dev/sdf5 not sda5**

My grub booloader assumes that the root device is on `/dev/sda5`.

I was thrown into a shell and a `cat /dev/sda` was answered with "no medium found". This, and the fact that the number of slots (5) in my card reader corresponds to the number of "low" device names (sda..sde) made me beleive that these devices were indeed my card reader.

So I unplugged the card-reader and the system booted okay.

Most of my partitions have labels and are listed in fstab with their labels, so once it finds root, the rest of the boot process is not a problem. Root however is listed as `/dev/sda5` in the grub config, so it needs to have this exact device name.

**A dirty fix**

I did not have this problem before I replaced my PSU. I may be using different USB ports than before, but other than that (and the new PSU) there is no difference to the previous setup.

So I plugged the card reader into another USB port and now the system boots most of the time, but not always.

**Different kernel fix**

My kernel is a `3.16.7-ckt25 #4 SMP PREEMPT` kernel, compiled from source. When I boot into the stock kernel (3.16.0-4-amd64), I don't have this problem. I doubt that it has anything to do with PREEMPT. I suspect it is a timing issue.

**Question**

- How can I tell my system to consistently give my USB card-reader device names *after* the sata harddisks?

Comment: You might probably want to write your own udev rules to properly enumerate the /dev directory: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev

Comment: Do udev rules apply to the boot phase when using grub with a ramdisk? Would udev rules allow to rename the devices or can just symlink them?

Comment: Udev starts at boot via a script, so this solution might be invalid to your case. You should probably also search some settings in BIOS related to peripheral enumeration ("PnP OS installed" or like maybe).

Comment: You can also specify boot disk via uuid which is pretty unique for the device, thus avoiding messing with udev and BIOS.

Comment: I don't think the BIOS has anything to do with it, because it finds the boodloader okay. It is the root passed to the kernel which causes the problems. Using UUIDs would of course fix the problem. But I want my old device naming and I don't like my card reader to be /dev/sda.

Comment: If you have udev included into your  initrd image, you can use custom udev  rules on boot to rename the devices.